# Being certain $G$ semigroup, is it group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, semigroups

I'm starting a course on algebraic structures in university, and this is one of the first problems. I want to know if my solution is valid. The question goes like this:

> Being $G$ non-empty semigroup (set with associative binary product).
> We know that $G$ verifies that:
>
> - $\exists e\in G:ex=x \forall x\in G$ ("left" neutral element).
> - $\forall x \in G, \exists y\in G : yx=e$ ("left" inverse element).
>
> Prove that $G$ is group.

My solution goes like this:
$$e=ee=(g^{-1}g)e=g^{-1}(ge)$$
Then necessarily $ge=g$, because $g^{-1}(ge)$ must be equal to $e$. So that proves that $e$ is in fact left and right neutral element of $G$.

Now, we see that:
$$g=ge=g(g^{-1}g)=(gg^{-1})g$$
and we conclude that $gg^{-1}=e$ because $(gg^{-1})g$ must be equal to $g$, so we conclude that $g^{-1}$ is left and right inverse element of $g$.

Given this, I conclude that $G$ is in fact group.

Is my reasoning correct? I'll thank any help.

Comment: Using the notation $g^{-1}$ before proving that there is a unique two-sided inverse is not a good idea.

Comment: It looks like you are using uniqueness of right inverses when you have $e=g^{-1}(ge)$ and conclude $ge=g$, aren't you?

Comment: @Christoph assume i wrote $y$ instead of $g^{-1}$. The proof is the same and is valid right? It's just notation

Comment: As I said: how did you get $ge=g$? I'm not even sure the task is properly stated: what is $e$ in the second condition, when the first condition doesn't assert uniqueness in "$\exists e$"?